# If I use GenerateionType.IDENTITY against an MS Sql Server, should I see that property on a column?

Tags: spring, hibernate

In my experience, whenever I set `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` on a column and look at the properties that are created on an MS Sql Server table, I don't find that the column is an *actual* identity.  Is this a bad assumption on my part, or bad configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for Oracle and MS SQL server you should use Generation type of sequence, you should also add the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation